# How to configure a UICollectionView Cell Size per Size Class?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm finding friction when trying to create responsive / adaptive `UICollectionViewCells` in the `UIStoryboard`.

The issue I'm seeing is that you don't seem to be able to set the `Cell Size` per `Size Class` and I'm trying to ascertain the right approach to this. I've designed the cells to adjust to their containers, so that they *should* autosize regardless of size class. This mostly works in that if I change the size class, select my cell view and do `Update Frames` then they all resize to fit their new size. However it's a one shot deal, if I go back to the Any/Any size class then I'm still seeing that resized version.

Here's what I'm aware I could try:

- Create multiple cells, with fixed dimensions, one per size class and in the Storyboard view. I could then only *use* the right one at runtime but I could then *see* them at design time.
- I *could* create a collection view Per Size class, each one only being installed for that size. This would work, but would be a pain to manage the multiple `UICollectionViews`
- Create my interface and/or constraints programmatically (losing visibility of the design).

I'm hoping this is a solved scenario and I'm just missing something, but I'm aware that it could be that the IB tools don't match the code at this point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution I came up with was just to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method.
This means that the cell dimensions can be set to match the available `Size Class` dimensions.

This still isn't ideal as you can't *see* the changes in the storyboard and you can't create a universal  design and see it in each of the different formats.

I'm still hoping someone has a better option.

Comment: I feel your pain, experiencing the same problems at the moment. It's even worse, as for some reason the running app does not take the right traits for the cells when I have different constraints for w any, h any and w regular, h regular - only after I added a dummy view only to the regular/regular size class it used those traits instead of the any/any ones. The size classes still need some attention from Apple it seems ...

Comment: Yes, just you don't have much choice now with all the new sizes *sigh*.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a similar solution coded-out in Swift. I just styled both of my cells in the storyboard and leave them viewable for any size class combination. When the trait collection changes I update the cellSize and cellReuseID I want to use and tell the collectionView to reload all the visible cells. Then

```
collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

and

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

(not shown in sample code) are called which lets me update the size of the cell and update the cell's storyboard styling. So not entirely done in storyboard, but good enough until more support is provided in Xcode.

```
struct MyCollectionViewConstants{
    static let CELL_ANY_ANY_REUSE_ID = "cell";
    static let CELL_COMPACT_REGULAR_REUSE_ID = "cellSmall"
    static let CELL_ANY_ANY_SIZE = 100;
    static let CELL_COMPACT_REGULAR_SIZE = 70;
}

class MyCollectionView: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var cellSize = MyCollectionViewConstants.CELL_ANY_ANY_SIZE
    var cellReuseID = MyCollectionViewConstants.CELL_ANY_ANY_REUSE_ID


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{

        return CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact
            && self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular){
            cellSize = MyCollectionViewConstants.CELL_COMPACT_REGULAR_SIZE
            cellReuseID = MyCollectionViewConstants.CELL_COMPACT_REGULAR_REUSE_ID
        } else {
            cellSize = MyCollectionViewConstants.CELL_ANY_ANY_SIZE
            cellReuseID = MyCollectionViewConstants.CELL_ANY_ANY_REUSE_ID
        }

        self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(
            self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using a flow layout you dont have to implement the delegate here for the item size, just set it on the layout itself- saves a lot of compution

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with same problem after implementing size class(iPad and iPhone).Well, I figured out a solution. Hope it helps!

Implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
         var device = UIDevice.currentDevice().model  
         var cellSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(155, 109)

         if (device == "iPad" || device == "iPad Simulator") {
            cellSize = CGSizeMake(240, 220) 
         }

         return cellSize
    }
```

Comment: Hey Alvin, that's what I went for in the end (see my answer above).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**
Hi Fellow Developers,

This is easy to do if the height and width of the UICollectionViewCell are same.

[image]

Steps
1. Import ** UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**
2. Add the **sizeForItem IndexPath** method of UICOllectionView as follows

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionVw.frame.size.height, height: collectionVw.frame.size.height)
}
```

*Note*: What happening is you are setting the height of the UICollectionView as height and width of the UICollectionViewCell

Happy Coding :)